# Boost sub_range with for_each; why am I getting a const-reference?

Tags: c++, boost

On OS X Mavericks, using boost 1.55.0 and clang-500.2.79 (based on LLVM 3.3svn), I'm trying to iterate over a sub-range in a `std::map` using `boost::for_each` and `boost:sub_range`. In my function-object, I expect to receive a std::pair &. Instead, I seem to receive a const std::pair &. Why?

```
#include <map>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/range/sub_range.hpp>

using std::map;
using std::begin;
using std::end;
using std::pair;
using boost::for_each;
using boost::sub_range;

int main()
{   
    map<int, int> myMap;
    sub_range<decltype(myMap)> s{
        begin(myMap),
        end(myMap)
    };

    auto f1 = [&](const pair<int, int> &) {
    };
    for_each(s, f1);    // Compiles fine

    auto f2 = [&](pair<int, int> &) {
    };
    for_each(s, f2);    // Fails to compile
}

/Users/ambarish> clang++ main.cxx 
In file included from main.cxx:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/map:371:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:18:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/algorithm:793:9: error: no matching function for call to object of type '<lambda at main.cxx:24:15>'
        __f(*__first);
        ^~~
/usr/local/include/boost/range/algorithm/for_each.hpp:80:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::for_each<std::__1::__map_iterator<std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::pair<int, int>, std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<int, int>, void *> *, long> >, <lambda at main.cxx:24:15> >'
      requested here
    return std::for_each<
           ^
main.cxx:26:5: note: (skipping 1 context in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
    for_each(s, f2);
    ^
main.cxx:24:15: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'value_type' (aka 'pair<__key_type, __mapped_type>') to 'pair<int, int> &' for 1st argument
    auto f2 = [&](pair<int, int> &) {
              ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't compile because the value type of `std::map<int, int>` is not `std::pair<int,int>` but `std::pair<const int, int>`.

The reason first one (`f1`) compiles is because `std::pair` has got this constructor:

```
template< class U1, class U2 >
pair( pair<U1, U2>&& p );
```

and because `f1` takes the argument by const reference. Now there's a suitable conversion which produces a temporary that can bind to a const reference easily.

Fix:

```
auto f2 = [&](pair<const int, int> &) { };
// or
auto f2 = [&](pair<int, int>) { };
```

Answer (score 0):

The code appears to be using std::for_each in the boost library implementation, and C++11 style standard lambdas are being passed to the for_each function at any rate. It really depends on how the library passes the container's iterators to the std::for_each